# MX Record, POP3 Server, Port 110

Tags: email

I have setup my DNS for my domain name and have a POP3 server on my VPS.

Now, I want to a run a POP3 mail server without SMTP just to receive emails It will run on port 110, the POP3 port of my VPS.

Is it possible to receive mails without running an SMTP server (port 25) but just a POP3 server on port 110. Can I disable the SMTP server on port 25 as I am not sending emails?

Comment: **Is it possible to receive mails without running an SMTP server, but just a POP3 server on port 110?** - No, it isn't.

Comment: Your mail client can receive mail from your server with just pop3, but your server cannot receive mail from other servers/senders without smtp.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

If you want to receive messages, you need a MTA ("Message Transfer Agent") listening on port 25. [Postfix](https://www.postfix.org/) is a popular MTA, and is what I use. All of the major Linux distros have Postfix in their various repositories.

Also, I recommend running an IMAP server, and not POP3, for handling client connections. [Dovecot](https://www.dovecot.org/) is a server that supports both of these protocols. Dovecot & Postfix [integrate](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql/) nicely together.